# What is the story of Lakshmi's son Chikleeta?

Tags: vedas, lakshmi, rig-veda

The [Khilani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khilani) of the Rig Veda contains the famous Sri Sukta, a hymn to Lakshmi goddess of wealth.  [This](http://www.stephen-knapp.com/prayers_to_goddess_lakshmi.htm) is what verses 11-12 of the Sri Sukta say:

> Sloka 11:  We are the progeny of our forefather, Sage Kardama, who is one of the sons of Goddess Lakshmi. We invoke that Sage Kardama to install in his family the Universal Mother, Mahalakshmi, who is decked with the garland of lotuses. So be it.
>
> Sloka 12: We invoke another son of Lakshmi named Chikleeta. May he dwell in our home and may his mother, Mahalakshmi, dwell in our family.

First of all, why is Kardama called a son of Lakshmi?  Kardama is a famous sage who was the father of the sage Kapila (an incarnation of Vishnu), and he is usually said to be born of Brahma's shadow (although the Harivamsa [calls](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/hv_1_30.html) him a descendant of Brahma's son Pulaha).  And I've heard that after the churning of the ocean Lakshmi made Kardama her adopted *father*, not son.  But do any other scriptures describe him as Lakshmi's son?

But my main question is, who is the figure mentioned in verse 12, Chikleeta?  Are there any scriptures that discuss his story?  The only information I could find about him is from [this webpage](http://www.kamakotimandali.com/srividya/srisukta.html), which says that Kardama and Chilkita are two of the seers of verses in the Sri Sukta:

> Each mantra of this Sukta has a different Rishi (seer), Chandas (metre), Devi (deity) and Viniyoga (ritual application). If we consider the entire Sukta as a whole, then the Rishis are: **Ananda, Chikleeta, Kardama, Shreeda and Indira, who are said to be the sons of goddess Lakshmi**

But is there any scriptural basis for Lakshmi having sons with these names?